# HALE: GML validation errors

Tags: xml, gml, validation, hale

I try to export a GML file from HALE editor but the validation has always errors with this text:

```
 The value '' of attribute 'gml:id' on element 'ps:ProtectedSite' is not valid with respect to its type, 'ID'., on line_, column_

  '' is not valid value for 'NCName' on line_, column_
```

Anybody can help me how to fix this errors?

Comment: what did you set the ID to be? and the NCName?

Comment: id was mapping to ID and i didn't find NCName

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the **value** of your `gml:id` attribute on your `ps:ProtectedSite` element is not valid (is not correct according to the schema).

So you probably have something that looks like:

```
<ps:ProtectedSite gml:id="">
```

It's telling you that the value of your gml:id is of type ID, and attributes of type ID must conform to a pattern defined by NCName.

> The type xsd:NCName represents an XML non-colonized name, which is simply a name that does not contain colons. An xsd:NCName value must start with either a letter or underscore (*) and may contain only letters, digits, underscores (*), hyphens (-), and periods (.)

Reference: http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_NCName.html